# How to set a file as an Embedded Resource in Rider IntelliJ?

Tags: .net, intellij-idea, embedded-resource, rider

I would like to set some of my **files as** ***Embedded Resource***s.

There are tutorials on the easy task like that, **only for Visual Studio**, but not for Rider.

Here is a question about *Rider* with no answer:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Jetbrains/comments/dw93rf/rider_add_file_a_embedded_resource/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got to **right-click on the file** (or the selected files - with Ctrl+A or Ctrl + left-click)

[image]

And then press **Properties** (or shortcut: **Alt+Enter**) and set *Editable/Build action* to ***EmbeddedResource***.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access it afterwards ? Answers on this topic dealing with Visual Studio instead of rider tell to access it via `<ProjectNamespace>.Properties.Resources.<file>` but the code analyzer outputs an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'"

Comment: @adamency In your project create a new class and add:              
`var rootType = typeof(MyClassWithEmbeddedFilesSomewhere);
 var resourceNames = rootType.Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();`